# Run Julia codes on a HPC server

Tags: bash, julia, cluster-computing, pbs

I aim to run some Julia codes  on a server (no complicated parallel processing involved) using a .pbs file (and qsub). It seems that I should first load module gcc and julia. But I can not find it

[module avail command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78WfH.png)

[load gcc error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzKdK.png)

So should I write gcc modulefile & julia modulefile myself? if so, how can I do it?
the following is my pbs file

[pbs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAGpc.png)

Comment: Hello, I think you should edit the title to specify "an HPC server"..

Comment: I don't think you need gcc. Also it seems neither julia nor gcc are available. Contact your HPC admin/IT and ask them to add Julia to the list of modules?

Comment: I agree that you should ask the admin to add a recent version of julia (at least 1.6+). If you want it now, you can download the generic linux version from the julialang website and place that in your home directory, and then add the julia bin to your path and you should be able to access `julia` from the command line.